# how to print a big string in REPL

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to read the content of a quite big string. When I ask to print it it replace the end of the string with '...(length: XXX)'

That's nice but I have no idea how to really see it.

```
debug> repl
Press Ctrl + C to leave debug repl
> sql
'SELECT project.* FROM tag2project, project WHERE tag2project.tag = \'7\' AND tag2p... (length: 131)'
```

Comment: `node-inspector` does the same thing, which I assume is related.  Would love to see an answer to this.

Comment: you could tried splitting the string into smaller chunks append newlines and then output. It would produce pretty output.